# is it possible to accept value from intent before oncreate

Tags: android, android-intent

I had fragmented my code so as to follow oop concept thus a code that appears in four activities was made into a separate activity of its own .. now this child activities actions depends on from which of the four parent activities it was called.. so the setContent view value varies according to the parent activity..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdf_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
```

Comment: You should really understand the Activity lifecycle and then rephrase your question, because as it is now. It's unclear what you want.

Comment: @Alvin I guess its possible to get values from intent before you call setContentView. That'll help you.

Comment: will you please explain,y you want this.

Comment: @Pankaj hope this explains..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...

all you have to do is to call the intent in the on create function before the setcontent view method..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
    String layout = intent.getStringExtra("layout");
    int id =getResourceUsingName(layout,"layout");

    setContentView(id); 
}
private int getResourceUsingName(String name, String type) {
    mContext=getApplicationContext();
    Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, type,
    mContext.getPackageName());
    return resourceId;
}
```